# Redux Jest is not receiving value as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I'm getting

> ```
>  Expected value to equal:
>
>   [{"id": 1, "text": "Run the tests"}, {"id": 0, "text": "Use Redux"}]
>
> Received:
>   [{"id": 0, "text": "Use Redux"}, {"id": 1, "text": "Run the tests"}]
> ```

I don't really understand on how to make this reducer test pass. I'm referencing various github projects to have a better understanding on testing. I'm not sure what i can do to make the test pass. Here is what i have.

Im testing using jest.

**actions/actions.js**

```
let nextTodoId = 0;

export const addPost = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_POST',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
})
```

**reducers/myPosts**

```
    const initialState = [
      {
        text: 'Use Redux',
        id: 0
      }
    ]



    const myPosts = (state = initialState, action) => {

      switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_POST':
          const post = {
            id:state.reduce((maxId, post) => Math.max(post.id, maxId), -1) + 1,
            text:action.text,

          }
          return [...state, post];


        default:
          return state
      }

    }

    export default myPosts
```

**tests**/reducers.js

```
import { addPost } from '../actions/actions';
import myPosts from '../reducers/myPosts';
import uuid from 'uuid';
describe('myPosts myPosts', () => {
  it('should return the initial state', () => {
    expect(myPosts(undefined, {})).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'Use Redux',
        id: 0
      }
    ])
  })
  it('should handle ADD_POST', () => {
    expect(
      myPosts([], {
        type: 'ADD_POST',
        text: 'Run the tests'
      })
    ).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'Run the tests',
        id: 0
      }
    ])
    expect(
      myPosts(
        [
          {
            text: 'Use Redux',
            id: 0
          }
        ],
        {
          type: 'ADD_POST',
          text: 'Run the tests',
          id:0
        }
      )
    ).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'Run the tests',
        id: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'Use Redux',
        id: 0
      }
    ])
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're expanding the previous state prior to adding the new post...

change your reducer to this:

```
return [post, ...state];
```

The way you wrote it... the new post is placed at the end of the state array.  If you want the new post to show up first this will fix the issue.

Comment: wow, thanks it works. I'm new to unit testing redux and react, what resources you recommend people like myself to go to ? Besides the resources you linked to. I will accept in 6 minutes

Comment: I have steered people towards code academy in the past.  https://www.codecademy.com/learn/react-101